# Converting streamed file content to base64 format

Tags: node.js

I've file coming from gridFS of mongoDB as stream. I need to convert the content into base64 format. My code looks something like this :

```
utils.readFileFromDb('fileID', "collectionName",
      function(err, result) {
var dbResult = result.pipe(base64.encode()));};
```

Here, I'm doing a mongoDB call and getting file based on file id from gridFS. The **result** of callback contains stream file content. I tried doing it using base64-stream module but getting result as object only.

Comment: Once the file is read completely use can use '.toString('base64')' to convert it into base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it something like this.

```
 var base64data = '';

 result.on('data', function(result) {
  base64data += new Buffer(result).toString('base64');

});

result.on('end', function() {
  console.log('dbResult : ' + base64data);
//do your stuff here with base64data wich contains string encoded in base64 format.....
});
```

Here, I'm converting every chunk getting from result to base64 and appending it in  **data** event.  In **end** event, I'm doing the stuff I need to do.

I hope It will help someone. Other answers will also be welcomed.

Comment: Don't you think you can have encoding problems with final parts of chunks, in case the chunk does not fit exacty in base64?